# Which option is better for Redis? SHUTDOWN or service stop?

Tags: redis, centos

I have Redis server running on CentOS as a service. I can stop the server using `service redis stop` or `redis-cli SHUTDOWN`.

What is the difference between the two options and which one I should be using in Production environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your init script since it may precisely perform a `shutdown` on stop and not a `killproc`, e.g:

```
ExecStop=/usr/bin/redis-cli shutdown
```

(from [Fedora package: redis-server.service](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/redis.git/tree/redis-server.service?id=0e8a54a51730260907f53e8c0d24d775dc0d7af3#n8))

Using `shutdown` is the recommended way to stop Redis if persistence matters as stated by the [documentation](http://redis.io/commands/shutdown):

> If persistence is enabled this commands makes sure that Redis is switched off **without the lost of any data**.

Comment: There is no custom init script. Yes persistence matters and that is the reason I inclined to use redis-cli SHUTDOWN but was not sure if service stop is essentially doing the same thing. Checked the redis config file and the stop() function has "killproc -p $pidfile $name". So I will use "redis-cli SHUTDOWN". Thanks for mentioning the point to check the confg file about the "service redis stop" behavior.